# version attributes behavior in bulk update

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

> > An application uses optimistic locking by defining version attributes in its entity classes. The application performs a bulk update of the entities using a JPQL query.In this case which of below statement is correct?
> >
> > > A.The persistence provider will ensure that the version value in each table is updated.
> > >
> > > B.The value of the Version attributes of the updated entitles should be also be explicitly updated by the query.

As per JPA specification

> "Bulk update maps directly to a database update operation, bypassing optimistic locking checks. Portable
>   applications must manually update the value of the version column, if desired, and/or manually validate
>   the value of the version column."

So as per my understanding option B is correct answer. But some of my colleague are saying other-way. Can you please tell me the correct behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, what it comes to specification A is definitely wrong answer.

Specific implementations of specification are still aloud to update value of @Version when JPQL bulk update is done. How certain implementation behaves is hopefully documented. When not, following can be used to check does bulk update affect version:

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity {
    @Id private int id;
    private String someValue;
    @Version private int version;
    //getters, setters
}

    //creating entity
    tx.begin();
    SomeEntity se = new SomeEntity();
    se.setId(1);
    em.persist(se);
    tx.commit();

    String versionJpql = "SELECT se.version FROM SomeEntity se WHERE se.id = 1";
    //original version
    Integer version = em.createQuery(versionJpql,Integer.class).getSingleResult();

    //bulk update
    tx.begin();
    em.createQuery(
            "UPDATE SomeEntity se SET se.someValue='some' WHERE se.id = 1"
    ).executeUpdate();
    tx.commit();

    Integer versionAfterUpdate = em.createQuery(versionJpql, Integer.class)
            .getSingleResult();

    //has version been changed:
    assertEquals(version, versionAfterUpdate);
```

Comment: Thanks Mikko for your help and example !!